# Elasticsearch cluster is crashing

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I do have script(This script is modification of azure arm script) to install elasticsearch cluster on Azure Linux but after latest updates my elasticsearch is failing almost everyday.

I can't find what is wrong with it and why my Elasticsearch nodes are crashing.

```
#!/bin/bash

help()
{
    echo "This script installs Elasticsearch on Ubuntu"
    echo "Parameters:"
    echo "  -n elasticsearch cluster name"
    echo "  -m configure as master node (default: off)"
    echo "  -h view this help content"
}

# Log method to control/redirect log output
log()
{
    echo "$1"
}

log "Begin execution of Elasticsearch script extension on ${HOSTNAME}"

if [ "${UID}" -ne 0 ];
then
    log "Script executed without root permissions"
    echo "You must be root to run this program." >&2
    exit 3
fi

# TEMP FIX - Re-evaluate and remove when possible
# This is an interim fix for hostname resolution in current VM
grep -q "${HOSTNAME}" /etc/hosts
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
  echo "${HOSTNAME} found in /etc/hosts"
else
  echo "${HOSTNAME} not found in /etc/hosts"
  # Append it to the hosts file if not there
  echo "127.0.0.1 ${HOSTNAME}" >> /etc/hosts
  log "hostname ${HOSTNAME} added to /etc/hosts"
fi

#Script Parameters
CLUSTER_NAME="es-azure"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle"

# Install Oracle Java
install_java()
{

    log "Installing Java"
    add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java -y
    apt-get update  -y 
    apt-get upgrade  -y 
    echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-2 select true | debconf-set-selections
    echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-2 seen true | debconf-set-selections

    apt-get update && apt-get install -y oracle-java12-installer

    apt install oracle-java12-set-default
}

install_es()
{
    wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add -
    apt-get install  -y apt-transport-https
    echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list    
    apt-get update -y 
    apt-get install -y elasticsearch
}

configure_es()
{
    log "Update configuration"
    mv /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.bak
    echo "cluster.name: $CLUSTER_NAME" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
    echo "node.name: ${HOSTNAME}" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
    echo "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
    echo 'discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.0.10", "10.0.0.11", "10.0.0.12"]' >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
    echo "network.host: _site_" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
    echo "bootstrap.memory_lock: true" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
    echo "node.data: true" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
    echo "node.master: true" >> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
}

configure_system()
{
    echo "options timeout:1 attempts:5" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
    resolvconf -u
    ES_HEAP=`free -m |grep Mem | awk '{if ($2/2 >31744)  print 31744;else printf "%.0f", $2/2;}'`
    echo "ES_JAVA_OPTS=\"-Xms${ES_HEAP}m -Xmx${ES_HEAP}m\"" >> /etc/default/elasticsearch
    echo "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" >> /etc/default/elasticsearch
    echo 'MAX_OPEN_FILES=65536' >> /etc/default/elasticsearch
    echo 'MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited' >> /etc/default/elasticsearch
    #https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html#systemd
    mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d
    touch /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d/override.conf
    echo '[Service]' >> /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d/override.conf
    echo 'LimitMEMLOCK=infinity' >> /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d/override.conf
    sudo systemctl daemon-reload

    chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch
}

start_service()
{
    log "Starting Elasticsearch on ${HOSTNAME}"
    systemctl daemon-reload
    systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
    systemctl start elasticsearch.service
    sleep 60

    if [ `systemctl is-failed elasticsearch.service` == 'failed' ] || [ `systemctl is-failed elasticsearch.service` == 'inactive' ];
    then
        log "Elasticsearch unit failed to start"
        exit 1
    fi
}

log "starting elasticsearch setup"
apt-get update  -y 
apt-get upgrade -y

install_java
install_es
configure_es
configure_system
start_service

log "completed elasticsearch setup"

exit 0
```

Elasticsearch Version: 6.8.1

Looks like issue is with Electing master:

```
[2019-07-09T03:34:26,311][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [master-vm2] zen-disco-node-failed({master-vm1}{0pN6r3YTQeO8-O5HVEww7g}{VzXCoYtBQsexnz5ervFHQA}{10.0.0.11}{10.0.0.11:93$
[2019-07-09T03:34:27,841][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [master-vm2] removed {{master-vm1}{0pN6r3YTQeO8-O5HVEww7g}{VzXCoYtBQsexnz5ervFHQA}{10.0.0.11}{10.0.0.11:9300}{ml.ma$
[2019-07-09T03:34:28,092][INFO ][o.e.i.s.IndexShard       ] [master-vm2] [.elastichq][3] primary-replica resync completed with 0 operations
[2019-07-09T03:34:28,094][INFO ][o.e.i.s.IndexShard       ] [master-vm2] [.elastichq][1] primary-replica resync completed with 0 operations
[2019-07-09T03:34:28,201][INFO ][o.e.i.s.IndexShard       ] [master-vm2] [production_results][1] primary-replica resync completed with 0 operations
[2019-07-09T03:34:28,253][INFO ][o.e.i.s.IndexShard       ] [master-vm2] [dev_results][3] primary-replica resync completed with 0 operations
[2019-07-09T03:34:28,467][INFO ][o.e.c.r.DelayedAllocationService] [master-vm2] scheduling reroute for delayed shards in [57.7s] (24 delayed shards)
[2019-07-09T03:35:57,178][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [master-vm2] Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[production_results][3]$
[2019-07-09T09:39:01,221][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.NativeController] [master-vm2] Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started
```

Comment: What's in the logs? This alone doesn't get us very far I'm afraid.

Comment: What version of ES is being installed here? `Discovery.zen` options have been deprecated, so if it's 7.2 that might be an issue - but then it probably wouldn't even start correctly?

Comment: @xeraa Added logs

Comment: @StefanoBranco Elasticsearch Version: 6.8.1

Comment: This looks pretty normal IMO. `Pause Young (Allocation Failure)` means that the space in the young generation has run out and the GC is now kicking in. The process just hangs afterwards? Because I can't see any crash / exit there. What's at the end of the log file (not the gc.log)?

Comment: @xeraa thank you you pointed me to right direction.

Comment: So you were able to solve it or is this just another hint? Might be https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25067 which is about too little memory or wrong settings for Docker.

Comment: @xeraa not yet, will be able to look into it in 2 days, but you pointed me to elastic logs, so now at least i can see crash logs